# audio.oncanplaythrough not worked on Internet explore

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement, On Api response updating beep sound should trigger. The solution which I used is worked in Chrome and Firefox browsers but it is not working on Internet Explorer.

```
if ($scope.totalQueueList) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'rest/assets/images/beep.mp3';              
    audio.oncanplaythrough = (event) => {
    var playedPromise = audio.play();
       if (playedPromise) {
        playedPromise.catch((e) => {
          console.log(e)
        if (e.name === 'NotAllowedError' || e.name === 'NotSupportedError') {
          console.log(e.name);
        }
        }).then(() => {

    });
    }
      }
    }
```

So anybody please help me out with how it works on Internet explore?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://caniuse.com onplaythrough attribute is not supported in IE.

However, you can instead addEventListener to the element, where the event is playthrough (no ‘on’).